# After reading csv file, is infinite returns true

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a simple read_csv() on a 1 year stock data downloaded from Yahoo finance.

```
 df2 = pd.read_csv(name2, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

This is for stock market prediction algorithm. The problem is, `np.isfinite(df2.all()))` is returning true for all the columns and I dont understand why. 
Because of this issue, my Random forest clf.fit() is throwing a value error that the numbers are too large to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the function is called isfinite, and it returns TRUE if the data is finite, false if the data is infinite or not a Number. Therefore I really believe the return True is what you would have expected in this case.

Please refer to: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html#numpy.isfinite